# Firebase / ReactJS, get last query in database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and reactjs. I was wondering to get the ID value 
of the last inserted query in reactjs with firebase. Thank you

```
firebase.database().ref().child("clients").orderByChild("ID").limitToLast(1)("value", function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var cellNum=childSnapshot.val().CellNum;

  });
});

this.setState(
{
  ID: cellNum

}, () => {

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that Firebase loads data asynchronously. Since this may take some time, it allows your code to continue. Then once the data is available, it invokes your callback with a snapshot of the data.

It's easiest to see this with some well-placed log statements:

```
console.log("Before starting query")
firebase.database().ref().child("clients").orderByChild("ID").limitToLast(1)("value", function (snapshot) {
  console.log("Got data");
});
console.log("After starting query")
```

When you run this code, it prints:

> Before starting query
>
> After starting query
>
> Got data

This is probably not the order that you expected. But it perfectly explains why the `setState` call in your code fails. When you call `setState` the data hasn't loaded yet.

The `cellNum` is only available inside the callback. So the call to `setState` also needs to be in that callback:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("clients").orderByChild("ID").limitToLast(1)("value", function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var cellNum=childSnapshot.val().CellNum;
    this.setState({
      ID: cellNum
    }, () => { });
  });
});
```